# Split template, script and styles (HTML, JS and CSS) in nuxt.js component files

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

What is the best way to split nuxt.js views, components (and layouts) into separate files (at design time, not after build)? With complex and large views and components I find it extremely annoying when I need to switch between template and script (to look something up, etc.).

Ideally, I would be able to define:

```
- foo.vue.html
- foo.vue.js
- foo.vue.css
```

and let the build/generate process do the rest. I am using generation of prerendered SPAs (`nuxt generate`) so the solution, if there is one, would have to be compatible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to do it somewhat manually like described in vue [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html#What-About-Separation-of-Concerns)

```
<!-- my-component.vue -->
<template>
  <div>This will be pre-compiled</div>
</template>
<script src="./my-component.js"></script>
<style src="./my-component.css"></style>
```