# NUXT 3 - seperate template in vue file, script in TS file, scss in scss file

Tags: typescript, vue.js, sass, vuejs3, nuxt3

How can we seperate template, script(TS), style(scss) individual file in nuxt3 ?

i have tried with the reference of nuxt2 but it did not work - https://stackoverflow.com/a/50956376/

Answer (score 2):

My way of **separating files** is using a **composable** *(Auto imported by Nuxt)* for my **logic**, and importing an scss file in the style tag, like this.

*My component File:*

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
  const { isLoadingComponent, fetchComponentData } = useComponent();

  fetchComponentData();
</script>

<template> 
  <ComponentLoader :is-loading="isLoadingComponent " /> 
</template>

<style lang="scss">
  @import 'file.scss'
</style>
```

*My composable file:*

```
export function useComponent() {
  const isLoadingComponent = ref<boolean>(false);

  const fetchComponentData = async () => { 
    isLoadingComponent.value = true;
    const data = await useFetch('api');
    isLoadingComponent.value = false;
  }
  
  return { isLoadingComponent, fecthComponentData };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.vue` files can load any of their tags using [`src` imports](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-spec.html#src-imports) with relative paths:

```html
<template src="./template.html"></template>
<style src="./style.scss" lang="scss"></style>
<script src="./script.ts" lang="ts"></script>
```

Make sure to read [*"What about separation of concerns?"*](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/sfc.html#what-about-separation-of-concerns)